# What is the story of Paurnamasi and Nandimukhi?

Tags: krishna, durga, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya, yashoda

Sri Rupa Gosvami, the disciple of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, has written two very beautiful plays called Vidagdha Madhava - Clever Krsna and Lalita Madhava - Charming Krsna.

Vidagdha Madhava describes the pastimes of Krsna in Vrndavana and Lalita Madhava those pastimes of Dvaraka.

Now both these dramas begin with an introduction by two characters **Paurnamasi** and **Nandimukhi**. They even appear during the interludes of the plays to add in some extra background story. So who are these two characters?

[This page](http://www.radhakunda.com/personalities/paurnamasi.html) describes Paurnamasi as the mother of Sandipani Muni (the Guru of Krsna and Balarama) and the disciple of Narada. Nandimukhi is said to be the daughter of Sandipani. Paurnamasi is also called the incarnation of Yogamaya. But then Yogamaya has incarnated as Yashoda's daughter. So does this mean there were two incarnations of Yogamaya?

P.S. Since I came across both Paurnamasi and Nandimukhi only in these two plays, I do not expect any references from sources other than Gaudiya Vaishnava literature. But if any exist, please do share them.

Comment: Interesting question.. could be fictional characters created for the play but may have been real too. I tried searching for Sandipani muni's genealogy but not getting much help.